# difference between unconditional and conditional community graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

With this question, I like to know the difference between the community structure of an `unconditional` directed graph and a `conditional` community graph. Here is a minimal example.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/909zu.png) I have a directed graph called `finalG` below:

```
EdgeList[finalG] 

finalG= {
"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", "MA2" \[DirectedEdge] 
"WHS", "MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "EST", 
"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", "CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
"CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "WHS" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
"WHS" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "WHS" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 
"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", "EST" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", 
"EST" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", "CST" \[DirectedEdge] "EST"
}
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yirWC.png) This list produces the following community structure:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[finalG, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, 
   Method -> "Hierarchical"]
```

[image]

[3] Now I find connected components in the graph `finalG` by

```
scc = ConnectedComponents[finalG]
```

which yields one connected component with elements, including

```
{{"MA2", "CO12", "WHS", "AGF", "EST", "CST"}}
```

[4] Finally, I like to draw the community structure contained in this single component by:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
   finalG, scc, 
   CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, Method -> "Hierarchical"
       ]
```

which yields the following community structure:

[image]

As is clear from my explanation, the difference between the two graphs (between [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yirWC.png) and [4]) of community structures is that the first one does not condition the graph to connected components, while the second one does. That is why (I think) we get two different community structures. In the community structure shown in [4], the vertex `EST` is not a member of the community.

My questions are as follows:

1. Can someone explain why the two community structures differ, although I use the same graph `finalG` in both cases and `scc` has the same directed linkages?
2. What is that I am doing (without knowing) in the second case with connected components that create a large community excluding `EST`?
3. I expected both cases to generate the same community structures because the graph `finalG` and the elements and linkages of the connected component `scc` are exactly the same.

Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: If you have a second argument like `scc` you are telling `CommunityGraphPlot` to use these communities you provided rather than calculate them itself. Since the graph is connected and `scc` includes all components, obviously it will draw one big community. Try this `CommunityGraphPlot[finalG, {{"MA2", "WHS", "EST", "CST"}, {"CO12", 
   "AGF"}}, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, 
 Method -> "Hierarchical"]` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: On point 2. / point 3. EST is not excluded - it's just a graphical glitch drawing the splines. Use a different method like `"SpringElectrical"` instead of `"Hierarchical"` and the problem goes away.

Comment: And on point 1. again, don't use `ConnectedComponents` because the whole graph is connected - use `FindGraphCommunities` instead if you want lists of the community vertices.

Comment: @flinty: First of all, thank you for your very useful points. My entire purpose of asking this question is that in a very large directed graph I first want to identify SCCs and then search for possible communities within SCCs. Since SCC and community graphs use different routines it may be possible that there are certain communities with the SCCs. Or the other way around: I should first find the communities and then investigate the SCCs within each community because a community member does not have to be linked to every other member in its community. Let me know what you think.

Comment: If you've got a large graph with multiple components which are not connected together, then you don't want `ConnectedComponents` because that just gives a list of vertices for each component. Instead, use `ConnectedGraphComponents` to get each component subgraph, then feed these to `CommunityGraphPlot`, e.g `CommunityGraphPlot[#,CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray,   Method ->"Hierarchical"]&/@ConnectedGraphComponents[biggraph]`. You will get a  list of plots, one community plot per connected subgraph.

Comment: @flinty: Excellent guidance. I will follow your point and see what happens...

Comment: @flinty: Your suggestions worked fine. However, in the `CommunityGraphPlot[...]` the colors of the edges or arrows became all blue color, although I have some edges with different colors. How can I preserve the original color scheme in my `biggraph`? Do you have any idea?